# One comma in space

Tags: php, regex

Find, for example in

`yyyy    ,     yyyy`

`yyyy,yyyy`

`yyyy,   yyyy`

`yyyy      ,yyyy`

the pattern between *yyyy* and *yyyy*.

I've tried:

`(\s*,{1}\s*)`

but this will also match

`yyyy,,yyyy`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bK5bC6/2)

What is missing?

Comment: Try this `\s+,{1}\s+`

Comment: Are you requiring a space? `\s*` is any amount of whitespace including none. Maybe...https://regex101.com/r/gB2xL5/1?

Comment: I'd say use `[^\s,](\s*,\s*)[^\s,]` but you're demo has `yyyy     yyyy` and my regex doesn't match that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **[lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**:

```regex
(?<![,\s])\s*,\s*(?![,\s])
```

- `(?<![,\s])` is a negative lookbehind `(?<!pattern)`. In this case, "*not preceded by a comma or a whitespace*"
- `(?![,\s])` is a negative lookahead `(?!pattern)`. In this case, "*not followed by a comma or a whitespace*"